# Can't set div's correct size

Tags: html, css

I have got two divs that located beside each other and they have got both parent div. 
My second div that has got `.redBlock` class but it is only makes background by symbols streight size. How to make that div size will be like parent's div size. Because I need that background will be smth like in a picture below. Where Cross means red background there too.[image]

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Phoneblock</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="phoneBlock blockContainer">
<div class="block1">
<img class="phone picture" src="phonicon.jpg" alt="phone">
<span class="phoneNumber semiBold"> phone</span> 
</div>
 <div class="redBlock block2">
 <span class="upperCase simpleTextColor tahoma">Block</span> 
 </div>
</div> 



</body>
<style type="text/css">

.pic{

}
.phoneBlock{
 height: : 500px;
 border:1px solid black;
}

.phoneNumber{
color: #d81e04;
}


.upperCase{
text-transform: uppercase;
}

.redBlock{
 height: 90px;
 background-color: #d81e04;
}

.simpleTextColor{
 color:#ffffff;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: SemiBold;
    src: url("MyriadPro-Semibold.otf") format("opentype");
}


@font-face {
    font-family: BlackIt;
    src: url("MyriadPro-BlackIt.otf") format("opentype");
}


.semiBold{
 font-family: SemiBold;
}

.blackIt{
font-family: BlackIt;
}
.tahoma{
 font-family: Tahoma;
}

.blockContainer{
    text-align:center;
}
.block1, .block2{
    display:inline;
}


</style>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `display:flex` in parent

**EDIT**

> how to put "BLOCK" word to bottom?

set `display:flex` in `.redBlock` and `align-self:flex-end` in child `span`

```css
.phoneBlock {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center/* align content horizontally */
}

.phoneBlock>div {
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.phoneNumber {
  color: #d81e04;
}

.upperCase {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.redBlock {
  display: flex;
    background-color: #d81e04;
}

.redBlock span {

  align-self: flex-end
}

.simpleTextColor {
  color: #ffffff;
}

img {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  max-width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="phoneBlock blockContainer">
  <div class="block1">
    <img class="phone picture" src="//placehold.it/90x90" alt="phone">
    <span class="phoneNumber semiBold"> phone</span>
  </div>
  <div class="redBlock block2">
    <span class="upperCase simpleTextColor tahoma">Block</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how to put "BLOCK" word to bottom?

Comment: but now, place where my cross located is without red background :D

Comment: you want all red  but the word at the bottom?? just change the `background` from `span`  to `redBlock`

Comment: I want red background only at BLOCK word and make it to parant's div boder height

Comment: thanx a lot :) u saved my time

Answer (score -1):

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Phoneblock</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="phoneBlock blockContainer">
<div class="block1">
<img class="phone picture" src="phonicon.jpg" alt="phone">
<span class="phoneNumber semiBold"> phone</span> 
</div>
 <div class="redBlock block2">
 <span class="upperCase simpleTextColor tahoma">Block</span> 
 </div>
</div> 



</body>
<style type="text/css">

.pic{

}
.phoneBlock{
 height: : 500px;
 border:1px solid black;
}

.phoneNumber{
color: #d81e04;
}


.upperCase{
text-transform: uppercase;
}

.redBlock{
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #d81e04;
    position: absolute;
}

.simpleTextColor{
 color:#ffffff;
    
}

@font-face {
    font-family: SemiBold;
    src: url("MyriadPro-Semibold.otf") format("opentype");
}


@font-face {
    font-family: BlackIt;
    src: url("MyriadPro-BlackIt.otf") format("opentype");
}


.semiBold{
 font-family: SemiBold;
}

.blackIt{
font-family: BlackIt;
}
.tahoma{
 font-family: Tahoma;
}

.blockContainer{
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.block1, .block2{
    display:inline;
}


</style>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

First Of all style a class in **CSS** like:

```
img.phone{

    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

Change also

```
.block1, .block2{

    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    float: left;
}
```

And Modify

```
.phoneBlock{

    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.redblock {
background-color: #d81e04;
}
```

Give this untested Code a try.

Comment: `Give this untested Code a try.` this is precious